# Which IoT protocol/framework for wireless M2M communication?

Tags: framework, iot, protocol

There has been a lot of Internet of Things open standards, protocols, frameworks and even full stacks emerging recently. But which of them is the most functional, interoperable and future-proof?

- [AllJoyn](https://www.alljoyn.org/) by AllSeen Alliance
- [AMQP](http://amqp.org/) by OASIS
- [CoAP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252) by IP for Smart Objects Alliance
- [DDS](http://portals.omg.org/dds/) by Object Management Group
- [HTTP](http://www.w3.org/) by W3C
- IoT Platform by Intel
- [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) by IBM
- [Open Interconnect Consortium](http://www.openinterconnect.org/)
- [Stomp](http://stomp.github.io/) by Stomp Spec Group
- [Thread](http://www.threadgroup.org/) by Thread Group
- [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) by Tavendo
- [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) by XMPP Standards Foundation
- [ZigBee](http://www.zigbee.org/) by ZigBee Alliance
- [Z-Wave](http://www.z-wave.com/) by Z-Wave Alliance

Is there any comparison of them?

*(Moved from StackOverflow)*

Comment: Please read: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-a-fair-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are basic comparisons of some protocols mentioned above:

- [Messaging Technologies for the Industrial Internet and the Internet of Things Whitepaper (PDF)](http://www.prismtech.com/sites/default/files/documents/Messaging-Comparison-Whitepaper-July2014.pdf)
- [Internet of Things: protocols war!](http://www.slideshare.net/paolopat/internet-ofthingsprotocolswar)
- [Choosing Your Messaging Protocol: AMQP, MQTT, or STOMP](http://blogs.vmware.com/vfabric/2013/02/choosing-your-messaging-protocol-amqp-mqtt-or-stomp.html)
- [IoT Protocol Wars: MQTT vs CoAP vs XMPP](http://www.iotprimer.com/2013/11/iot-protocol-wars-mqtt-vs-coap-vs-xmpp.html)
- [Beyond MQTT: A Cisco View on IoT Protocols](http://blogs.cisco.com/ioe/beyond-mqtt-a-cisco-view-on-iot-protocols/)
- [Understanding The Protocols Behind The Internet Of Things](http://electronicdesign.com/embedded/understanding-protocols-behind-internet-things)
- [Internet of Things (IoT) protocols COAP MQTT OSCON2014](http://www.slideshare.net/vgholkar/io-t-protocolsoscon2014)
- [Protocols for Internet of Things](http://www.slideshare.net/mustnotgrumble/protocols-for-internet-of-things-39958144)
- [IoT Conference Berlin: M2M, IoT, device management: one protocol to rule them all?](http://www.slideshare.net/jvermillard/iot-conference-berlin-m2miot-device-management-one-protocol-to-rule-them-all)

Among them, MQTT seems the most promising.

*(If you have more to add, please edit this answer)*